# I am having trouble with installing OpenCV on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, face-recognition

I have been trying for the past 2 weeks trying to get OpenCV running on my raspberry pi. I have followed multiple different tutorials from different sources such as core electronics, pimylifeup, etc and nothing has worked. Yesterday, I decided to install it on my Mac and it worked perfectly with no flaws. The command I used was: pip3 install opencv-python. I then tried to install this on a fresh install of the OS on my raspberry pi and it still doesn't work. Any ideas as to why this installed on my Mac so easily which I've never used for python before compared to my PI?

I thought when replicating the exact steps I took on my MacBook it would work on my Pi. The most recent error I get when running is this:

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap
    native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ImportError: /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cv2/cv2.abi3.so: undefined symbol: __atomic_store_8
```

Other errors I got before were simply unable to import cv2

Comment: Which OS is installed on your PI?

Comment: I have tried both Buster and Bookworm

Comment: @Liam Truran. Be patient.  awaiting Cross-Compiler Toolchain for Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm. Once the toolchain becomes available from webiste. It is too early.

Comment: You may wanna to try this  https://orcacore.com/system-locale-setup-debian-12-bookworm-command-line. I haven't try it yet. Another one is awating https://lindevs.com/install-precompiled-opencv-on-raspberry-pi/#write-comment