# OpenCV Raspberry Pi Error Could not build wheels

Tags: python, opencv, pip, raspberry-pi, python-wheel

I'm attempting to install OpenCV on my Raspberry Pi 3B+, and I'm encountering an issue during the installation using pip install. I consistently receive the following error message:

***ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python
Failed to build opencv-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects***

Is there an updated method for installing OpenCV (cv2) on the Raspberry Pi, or is there a pre-installed system image available that includes OpenCV?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There was a very similar question recently and it got zero answers. The other question even posted a link to a whole thread of answers and claimed that none of them worked. I'm short, don't rely on this question to solve your problem. Keep searching and trying things while you wait (maybe forever) for an answer.

Comment: @OysterShucker could you provide some useful information, such as a link to the Question?..

Comment: is there any more error text? what operating system and version are you using (perhaps a Raspbian variant)? do you have build-essential? do other wheels work?

Comment: @ti7 Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (Bullseye)

Comment: @ti7 - [found it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77367648/i-am-having-trouble-with-installing-opencv-on-raspberry-pi-4). No link to thread of answers though. I think I was confusing 2 different posts.

Comment: hmm.. please add the complete error - do you have `build-essential` installed (`sudo apt install build-essential`)? does upgrading pip/setuptools help? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65662375/failed-to-build-opencv-contrib-python-on-rasberry-pi) `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`

Comment: According to a bunch of reading around regarding OpenCV and RPi, even if you get it to work it is likely to run out of memory very quickly. You will be very limited on how much you can actually do with OpenCV on an RPi, and the fact you are using a 3b+ is putting you at an even further deficit.

Comment: @OysterShucker do you have links to these? if you have concrete evidence "this won't work" or a strong case for "this is a bad idea" recommendations, make it an Answer!

Comment: @ti7 I don't write answers from my phone - which is all I have ATM. It takes almost no effort to find this information. I Google searched "OpenCV won't install RPi". The forum style results have everything I said.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/92920/cant-install-opencv-on-my-pi) will help. Basically it's a "compile it yourself" answer with varying mileage.

Comment: @OysterShucker  thanks. I quickly followed the guide, and it worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, it actually worked to install cv2. The following guide worked for me:

> wget https://github.com/prepkg/opencv-raspberrypi/releases/latest/download/opencv.deb

> sudo apt install -y ./opencv.deb

> opencv_version --> to check the version

> rm -rf opencv.deb --> delelte unsessesarry file

Then, I checked if I can import cv2 in a Python file, and it worked out. Thank you.

Here is the link to the original post: https://lindevs.com/install-precompiled-opencv-on-raspberry-pi/#write-comment

Comment: If you have time, update this answer after you've used it for a while with the performance that you get. The consensus seems to be that it's not going to run great and I'm curious how accurate that is.